# Synchronize across two ScheduledExecutorService task pools

Tags: java, multithreading

Trying to figure out how to do concurrency properly in Java. I have two groups of tasks. Tasks within a group do not interfere with one other, and so may be run concurrently without problems. However, tasks of one group should not be running while any task of the second group are running.

First group runs every 10 minutes. 
Second group runs every hour.
I am using two ScheduledExecutorService to schedule the two groups.

Ideally, every task would need to check if any of the tasks in the second group are running, wait or them to finish, and then run.

I tried solving this with locks, and came up with something like this:

```
    lock1.lock();
    try {
        while (!lock2.tryLock()) {
            wait();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            System.out.println("Test1 @@@@@@@@@");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        lock1.unlock();
    }
}
```

Where lock1 would be shared by the first group, lock 2 by the second. But this way, I am forcing all the tasks of the first group to wait for the common lock.

What would be an elegant way to go about this problem?

Comment: Are you happy if the jobs interleave with one another or must an entire group finish before the second group starts?

Comment: The ones from different groups should not interleave.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to achieve such a task with two independent `Lock`s is very complicated and error-prone. What you need is much similar to `ReadWriteLock` where two `Lock`s preclude each other. The only difference is that *both* locks should be non-exclusive, just like the `ReadLock`.

Such a lock pair can be implemented straight-forward similar to how `ReentrantReadWriteLock` works. The example below uses a single atomic int state value which will represent the reentrant lock count combined with the sign of the value telling which group owns the lock. Like with most lock implementations, a value of zero indicates that the lock is free.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;

public class TwoGroupLock {

  private final Sync sync=new Sync();
  private final Lock group1, group2;

  public TwoGroupLock() {
    group1=new L(+1);
    group2=new L(-1);
  }

  public Lock getGroup1Lock() {
    return group1;
  }

  public Lock getGroup2Lock() {
    return group2;
  }

  private final class L implements Lock {
    private final int group;

    L(int i) { group=i; }
    public void lock() { sync.acquireShared(group); }
    public void lockInterruptibly() throws InterruptedException {
      sync.acquireSharedInterruptibly(group);
    }
    public boolean tryLock() { return sync.tryAcquireShared(group)>=0; }
    public boolean tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit)
        throws InterruptedException {
      return sync.tryAcquireNanos(group, unit.toNanos(time));
    }
    public void unlock() { sync.releaseShared(group); }
    public Condition newCondition() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
  }
  private final class Sync extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer {
    protected @Override int tryAcquireShared(int group) {
      for(;;) {
        final int state=getState();
        if(state!=0 && (state^group)<0) return -1;
        if(compareAndSetState(state, state+group)) return +1;
      }
    }
    protected @Override boolean tryReleaseShared(int group) {
      for(;;) {
        final int state=getState();
        if(state==0 || (state^group)<0)
            throw new IllegalMonitorStateException();
        if(compareAndSetState(state, state-group)) return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It’s not necessary to understand all its internal details for using the class. Just similar to ReadWriteLock you have two methods for getting either of the associated locks and like the `ReadLock`, multiple threads can acquire a lock but only if no thread holds the other lock. The two locks are symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Using the condition queue for this purpose seems like an excellent idea, especially for waiting on a condition to become true or false.

However, I suggest that you use the [`Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) libraries from [`Lock#newCondition()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#newCondition()).

Here is an example off the top of my head:

```
public class Waiter {
    // Happens-before is strong enough to make sure the view
    // of running is visible to other threads
    // Even if the lock is not held, writes to a boolean
    // is atomic and non-compound, therefore, no synchronization
    // is needed because threads cannot be interleaved
    private boolean running = false;

    private final ReentrantLock taskLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition condition = this.taskLock.newCondition();

    public void check() throws InterruptedException {
        if (!this.taskLock.isLocked()) return;
        while (this.running) this.condition.await();
    }

    public void run() {
        this.taskLock.lock();
        this.running = true;
    }

    public void done() {          
        // Wait for the while loop to finish,
        // Release the threads held in the queue,
        // then the lock can be released            
        try {
            this.running = false;
            this.condition.signalAll();
        } finally {
            this.taskLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public static final Waiter WAITER = new Waiter();

// First task
WAITER.run();
try {
    // ...
} finally {
    WAITER.done();
}



// Second task
try {
    WAITER.check();
} catch (InterruptedException x) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    x.printStackTrace();
}
// ...
```